# ASP.NET built-in cache (HttpContext.Cache) - is anyone using this stuff?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Developers who are looking to leverage a side cache from ASP.NET seem to have an embarassment of riches / choices these days:

1. The built-in ASP.NET cache (HttpContext.Cache)
2. AppFabric on-premise
3. AppFabric Azure
4. Redis Azure
5. Other third-party

If you haven't heard, Microsoft announced the end of life for #2.  That (plus the existence of #4) makes me wonder whether #3 is a good long-term bet.  But my real question is about #1.  I've been in the ASP community a long time & I seldom hear about (or see) corporate uses of the built-in cache.  Maybe other developers know something I don't?  It sucks?

My company is pursuing #5.  We were thinking of abstracing away from the vendor's API, perhaps using an interface based on #1's semantics, but if #1 was a non-starter from day one, what would be the point?      --Thanks, BGU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: [ObjectCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.objectcache?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a Microsoft-provided abstraction over both MemoryCache and AppFabric.  It should be used as the abstraction over third-party products, too, if loose coupling is desired.  (And that is what we ended up doing.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently (last year or so) used the built in cache in an intranet environment to store 13Mb of slowly changing (once a day) data.  The benefits for me were... ease of use, reliability and, because the built in cache is part of IIS, there were no additional dependencies (e.g. routing/firewalls) so less to go wrong.

Is the built-in cache in common use now?  I've no idea, I rarely used it before, or since.  Nevertheless it works and seems likely to be around for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

1. **ASP.Net Cache** *(actually **HttpRuntime.Cache**)* it is a fastest of all and prefer method, if you do not plan to host as Web Farm or Web Garden.
2. **Windows Server AppFabric** - You can use this if you plan to host as Web Farm or Web Garden. *It requires a lot of configuration; I personally prefer **Redis Cache**.*
3. **AppFabric Cache** is already retired in Azure. Next, **Azure In-Role Cache** will be also retired soon.
4. **Redis Cache** - It is currently a recommended method, if you plan to host in Azure.

*The bottom line is if it is a single instance, I'll definitely use **HttpRuntime.Cache**. However, I personally prefer **Redis Cache** for Web Farm or Web Garden.*